# Cookie missing when called in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good day..!  I have some issue getting the value of my cookie when called in a class..

here's my code in my default.aspx.. I can retrieve the value on the when inside the aspx page

```
  HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("SAMPLE");
  myCookie["value"] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value);
  myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
  Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

  if (Request.Cookies["SAMPLE"] != null)
        {
            string userSettings;
            if (Request.Cookies["SAMPLE"]["value"] != null)
            { userSettings = Request.Cookies["SAMPLE"]["value"]; }
 }
```

But when i called the cookie inside a class using this code        HttpUtility.UrlDecode(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SAMPLE"]["value"]) it doesn't have any value.. Any idea..? Hope to hear from you soon..

Regards,

Link

Comment: Are you sure httpContext is available inside your class. No matter what it is a bad idea of using HttpContext inside a class as you are making the class totally dependent on web context. Can not be reused for windows form application. Would suggest you to inject the value into the class.

Comment: Where did you make an object of this class? Share the code where you calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with `Response`

```
 ....
 Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);

if (Response.Cookies["SAMPLE"] != null)
{
...
}
```